# Angular PrimeNG Editor Get Multiple Instances

Tags: angular, primeng, quill

Hi I'm using prime ng editor with angular and got multiple primeNg editors

### x.component.html

```
<p-editor [modules]="quillConfiguration"  formControlName="questionName" id="questionContents" [style]="{'height':'90px'}" (onTextChange)="onTextChange($event,'questionName')"></p-editor>

<p-editor [modules]="quillConfiguration"  formControlName="questionDesc" id="questionDesccontents" [style]="{'height':'90px'}" (onTextChange)="onTextChange($event,'questionDesc')" ></p-editor>

<p-editor [modules]="quillConfiguration"  formControlName="guidelines" id="guidelinesContents" [style]="{'height':'90px'}" (onTextChange)="onTextChange($event,'guidelines')"></p-editor>

<p-editor [modules]="quillConfiguration"  formControlName="{{item.attributeName}}" id="contents{{item.attributeName}}" [style]="{'height':'90px'}" (onTextChange)="onTextChange($event,item.attributeName)"></p-editor>
```

### x.component.ts

```
import * as Quill from 'quill'
import { Editor } from "primeng/editor";

@ViewChildren(Editor) editorCmp : QueryList<Editor>;
public quillConfiguration = {
toolbar: {
container: [...], 
handlers: {
'customStyles': (value) => { 
const selectionRange = this.quill.getSelection();  //throwing error cannot read properties of undefined(reading getSelection) 
   } 
  }
 }
};
private quill: undefined | Quill;
```

Using `@ViewChildren()` I'm accessing editor and calling getQuill method on it

x.component.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.editorCmp.changes.subscribe(editor => {
      editor.toArray().forEach((edit, idx) => {
        this.quill = edit.quill
      })
    })
 }
```

I'm not sure is this the correct way to get editor instance, only the last `p-editor` gets the instance, not sure how we can get for all?

Answer (score 0):

`ViewChildren` gives you a list of all the items that match your query, which is `Editor`. You get a list of the 4 editors you're using.

In `ngAfterViewInit`, when you subscribe to `this.editorCmp.changes`, `editor` gets the 4 editors. Then you use forEach in them and for each one you assign `edit.quill` to `this.quill`. Because of this, only the last assignment actually holds since you overwrite the first 3 assignments.

If you want to store all 4 you can do it like this:

##### x.component.ts

```
private quills: undefined | Quill[]; // Change to array of Quill


ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.editorCmp.changes.subscribe((editors) => {
        this.quills = editors.map((editor) => editor.quill);
    })
 }
```